# Array not helping speed

Tags: arrays, vba, if-statement

I created an array to speed up this but it seems to take forever to run still. Is there are way to say once the first If is satisfied move to next i? It seems to find the match (always only one) but still search through all of the annualArray.

Do give detail i have ID's on one table and want to find the matching ID on another table, then pull the date from the second table and put it into the first table (and subtract by todays date)

```
Set report = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
Set uwat = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("UWAT")

For i = 2 To report.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For Z = 2 To annual.UsedRange.Rows.Count
annualArray1 = Worksheets("Annual").Range("B1:T2000").Value

If CLng(report.Cells(i, 1)) = annualArray1(Z, 1) And annualArray1(Z, 19) <> "" Then
       report.Cells(i, 19) = Date - CDate(Mid(annualArray1(Z, 19), 16, 10))
    End If

Next Z
Next i
```

Comment: Yep. After the line that says `report.Cells(i, 19) = Date - CDate(Mid(annualArray1(Z, 19), 16, 10))` in your `If` block, just stick a `Exit For` and it will exit your `Z` loop.

Comment: You're still writing to individual cells in a loop...

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks!

Comment: Mathieu im new to arrays, how do i not do that

Comment: `annualArray1` is being overwritten with the same identical values at every single iteration of the `Z` loop, for one. Consider putting up the actual full procedure scope & context on [codereview.se] if you want help making it more efficient & better in every aspect - that's precisely what CR does.

Comment: How would I get it to go through each one without the loop

Comment: @JoshHudson Just move `annualArray1 = Worksheets("Annual").Range("B1:T2000").Value` outside of your loops and put it under the `Set`s - you're wasting run-time by assigning that value every single iteration of your `Z` loop.

Comment: You guys have been great. Looks like just about everything is working. But now when i run the below i get a subscript out of range error when it hits the last row in the array and a match inst found

    If report.Cells(y, 19) = "" And report.Cells(y, 3) <> "LOW" Then
    If CLng(report.Cells(y, 1)) = myArray(r, 1) Then
    report.Cells(y, 19) = Date - DateValue(myArray(r, 2))
    Exit For

    End if
    End if

Next y
Next r